# Python 2.5 socket._fileobject is what in Python 3.1?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm porting some code that runs on Python 2.5 to Python 3.1. A couple of classes subclass the socket._fileobject:

```
class X(socket._fileobject):
  ....
```

Is there an equivalent to socket._fileobject in Python 3.1? A quick scan of the source code doesn't turn up anything useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Python 3 uses SocketIO instead of _fileobject in the makefile() method, so that's probably the way to go.